# How to keep a mobile device from switching off its display when showing a HTML page

Tags: android, html, ios, mobile, windows-phone

is it possible to tell a mobile browser, that as long as a certain HTML page is displayed, the device should not turn off its screen?

I want to build something like [Project Blinkenlights](http://blinkenlights.net/blinkenlights), but every participant brings his/her own pixel. To set each display to a certain color at a given point in time is managable, just let each one open a website that shows a blank page and changes the background to color the screen. I'd use JavaScript to link the devices and have them log into a control server. But having the pixels wink out because the devices go to sleep would somehow break the concept.

A dedicated app would be overkill, and not every passing onlooker would install an app anyway (at least I wouldn't).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I hope, this is not possible. And even if it should be, that would be very OS specific. However, I am scared about websites that can control the power saving settings of my mobile device.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure you can't do that without bundle your webview inside an app. And whatever is the OS. It's all about protecting the user (and his device battery)