# Block iOS/Android device from locking the screen/energysaving mode

Tags: android, ios, google-chrome, mobile, safari

I have a two-device setup,

1. (A) controls via Native App
2. (B) is used as a display via the Browser/Websockets (best on a Tablet/iPad)

Is there any way you people might have heard of that I could block device B from going into energy-saving mode, while I need it as a display?

I mean, could I cause something with the Websocket-connection, like a refresh?

It can be some chrome/safari specific workaround, obviously the people playing html-videos must have a way of doing this.

EDIT: I just checked, when you watch a youtube video in the browser, the phone doesn't go to sleep either. So as long as the video is playing it must tell the browser to not fall asleep or something.

Comment: Same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12108175/how-to-keep-a-mobile-device-from-switching-off-its-display-when-showing-a-html-p?rq=1

Comment: well the question is for both iOS and Android. And I wanted to ask because when you play a video in html it doesn't stop either. SO there has to be something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is difficult as the timeout is set at the system level. When you make a call like

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setIdleTimerDisabled:YES];
```

It is essentially accessing a function from within the iOS, right? With a webpage, that would be impossible. However, as you have mentioned, a device screen usually doesn't time out while playing youtube. I think in general, for most devices, when it is playing a video, the screen wont timeout.

Maybe you can try putting a < video > tag that plays a 1pixel 1sec video, and then keep replaying the video with javascript. This should work for some device, but not all. For instance my Nexus4 timesout even when I am watching Youtube (and I blame my custom rom for that). If you are using this across different devices, you will also have to make sure you provide the correct format of video to different device and browsers, here is a chart from wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5_video#Browser_support

Comment: Thanks, that's at least a start :)

Answer (score 2):

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setIdleTimerDisabled:YES];

Comment: Yes, that's what we do in native Apps. I asked what I can do on Device B.

Answer (score 1):

Here is solution for Android:

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity{
    private WakeLock wakeLock;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle){
        String TAG = "your tag";
        PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
        wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK, TAG);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        wakeLock.acquire();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
         wakeLock.release();
         super.onPause();

    }
}
```

Your app will never go into idle mode until the moment your release 'wakeLock'. You also can find two additional examples [here](http://blog.blundell-apps.com/tut-keep-screen-onawake-3-possible-ways/).

Comment: Sorry, I don't see how I get this run inside a webpage in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

If, as you say, playing a video does what you want, how about embedding a small blank and silenbt video that can be put into an endless repeat in the page that device B is displaying?

Comment: That's the idea, what could be a sort of standard-unobstrusive approach? Some pointers to which html element to use?